# Hive ODBC connecting to HDInsight

Tags: azure, odbc, sql-server-2012, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm setting up a VM SQL server in Azure and I want it to be able to connect to Hive on a HDInsight cluster. I'm trying to set the ODBC DSN up and I'm unsure of what the various settings are and how to find them in my Azure portal:

1. Hostname
2. Username
3. Password (can I reset this if I've forgotten it)

Cheers, Chris.

Comment: I've got this working but I'd still like to know how to reset the password in case I forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hostname: HDinsight cluster name
- Username: HDInsight cluster username
- Password: HDinsight cluster password

I don't think you can recover the password.  You can delete the HDInsight cluster, and create another one cluster.  Because Hadoop jobs are batch jobs, and HDInsight cluster usually contains multiple nodes, poeple usually create a cluster, run a MapReduce job, and delete the cluster right after the job is completed.  It is too costly to let an HDInsight cluster sitting in the cloud.

Because HDInsight cluster uses Windows Azure Blob storage for data storage, deleting a cluster will not impact the data.